# Get value from file

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to do a query with a `where` clause that matches against a list of values from a `.csv` file ?

Something like:

```
 Select thingA * from 
 table1 where thingB exists in csv file
```

Comment: You can use `OPENROWSET`

Comment: I would advice loading your CSV to a table first (with SSIS, SSMS' wizard or `openrowset` if the file is on the same server or accessible) and then using SQL to do your conditions, specially if it's a big CSV or you have complex validations or manipulations to do.

Comment: there is about 2500 rows but the operation is not complex. What can happen if i would use the values directly from the file?

Comment: @Lautaro You can use `OPENROWSET` directly in that case.

Comment: Im not sure im using OPENROWSET correctly. I keep getting all data as one row. Ive made another question for this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211147/openrowset-returns-just-one-row

Answer (score 1):

Using the technique described in [Use SPLIT_STRING with OPENROWSET](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/use-split-string-with-openrowset):

Assume that my text file has 3 rows with values (one, two and three)

```
--Setup demo data
DECLARE @T table (ID int, ThingB varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @T (ID,ThingB) VALUES 
(1,'one'),(4,'four')

--Declare variables
DECLARE @CrLf CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @BulkColumn VARCHAR(max)

--Replace CR/LF with tilde (because tilda is not in my txt file)
SELECT @BulkColumn = replace(BulkColumn, @CrLf, '~')
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\z.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile

--Select id from @T table where ThingB exists in the values
--from the text file
SELECT ID
FROM @T t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM string_split(@BulkColumn, '~')
        WHERE value = t.ThingB
        )
```

---

```
| ID |
| 1  |
```