# OPENROWSET returns just one row

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

Im trying to import values from a `.csv` file which has only one column. I keep getting all the values in just one row.

```
SELECT BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Temp\myfile.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile
```

Here is a sample of the first rows of the files content

```
Nummer
072XXXXXX63
072XXXXXX76
07XXXXXX66
072XXXXXX4
```

Comment: [Jeff Moden](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost910065.aspx) has a plausible solution for this.

Comment: Why not use [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) where you can control all sorts of things, including specifying a row terminator?

Comment: @AaronBertrand because i do not want to add the values to a table. I just need them for a query. But ive figured that BULK INSERT into a temporary table is probably the best way to go. I dont really get temp tables though. They are created and exist just like normal tables.

Comment: There are a lot of differences. A #temp table is created in tempdb, is only visible to *your* session, and so two users can create `#foo` at the same time and not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 4):

The [OPENROWSET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) describes the `SINGLE_CLOB` option as:

> returns the contents as a **single-row, single-column** rowset of type varchar(max)

So you will either need to split the string into multiple columns using the [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function (or a similar method), use a [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#input-file-format-options) to specify a row terminator for `OPENROWSET`, or use [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which allows you to specify a row terminator without the need to create a format file.

You could adapt the following code by customizing the `FIELDTERMINATOR` and `ROWTERMINATOR` as necessary for your input file. For example, the following code was tested on [your provided sample file](https://gist.github.com/pattertall/dd8ff283ee3a7900b043993d917c3537):

```
CREATE TABLE #bulkInsert (col1 NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)

BULK INSERT #bulkInsert
FROM 'C:\Temp\myfile.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = N','
    , ROWTERMINATOR = N'0x0a' /* See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26758288/1582862 */
    , BATCHSIZE = 50000
    , TABLOCK
);

-- The sample rows were correctly bulk loaded, including the header row,
-- which you can remove from your file or filter out after bulk loading
SELECT *
FROM #bulkInsert
--Nummer
--072XXXXXX63
--072XXXXXX76
--07XXXXXX66
--072XXXXXX4
```

Comment: After executing  i ran SELECT * FROM #bulkInsert and got only empty rows. Millions of empty rows.

Comment: @Lautaro I added a test case using your provided sample file and updating the field terminator to match the file. I'm seeing the correct rows, so if it's not working for you it would be useful to link to the exact sample file that is not working as you expect and include the exact T-SQL you are using to process that sample file.

Comment: I can only get it to work if i change it to "FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' " 
But still the temp table gets more than a million rows when the file only has 2500.

Comment: I appologize! It turns out that the file actually contains a million empty rows after the values. Thank you for your help!